# Theoretical lower limit to the density of a planet

Tags: astrophysics, planets, density

If a celestial body is too dense, hydrogen fusion will ignite and it will become a star. As such, there is an upper limit on the density a planet can have. 
But is there a lower bound on the density that a planet can have? Is there any reason a planet couldn't be arbitrarily non-dense?

So far, groups ([Masuda 2014](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.2885), [Roberts et al.](https://www.exoplanetscience2.org/sites/default/files/submission-attachments/exoplanets2_roberts_kepler51b_51d_spectra.pdf)) have found densities of around $\rho\sim0.03\text{ - }0.06\text{ g cm}^{-3}$ for planets in the Kepler-51 system. Can we expect to keep finding planets even much dense than that?

Comment: Sure, depending on its exact mass, a self-gravitating sphere of pure hydrogen will have the lowest mass. You can't go arbitrarily low-density though, as this would translate into a large radius of the planet, and at some point mass loss from this will occur, and self-regulate the planet to a lower mass.